# Whitelist available in Apple Mail for automatic Load Remote Content when this option is deselected in settings?

Tags: macos, mail.app

The 'Load Remote Content' is a great feature and I like to use it. Is there a way to make a whitelist of sender addresses for which remote content is loaded automatically, whilst remote content of addresses not on the whitelist are not automatically loaded?

Such whitelist will help me having the media content local and therefore the emails readable even after some time (media may have been deleted on server side by the sender after some time).

In addition such whitelist will be more productive, since I do not have to press for each email the button 'Load Remote Content'. Today many companies send their brand in an image, or add images to direct the reader to their Facebook/Twitter or whatever social media page. For these message I always have to press the button 'load remote content' since I do not know if other media content may have been added to the body of the email which the sender wants to share with me (eg photo).

The reason why I do not want to automatically load remote content is to not give feedback to spammers that my email addresses are active. Spammers usually work with a small media added to the email (usually 1 pixel image). When spammers see your email address active, they 1) continue spamming you 2) selling/giving your email addresses to other spammers.

Comment: another version with no answers : https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317407/set-load-remote-content-in-messages-per-sender?rq=1

Answer (score -2):

You can try using Mail's built-in Rules.

It is located here:

**Mail** -> **Preferences...** -> Rules -> Add Rule

[image: Mail Rules]
Then you can fill up the info.
Like for example, let's say there is Facebook sending you an email every day. You can add a rule to maybe send it to the inbox or you can archive it etc.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. There is nothing you can do with Rules to load remote content.